# Does mailchimp support HTML5 animation

Tags: html, svg, mailchimp

I'm a beginner so please bear with me. I have no idea about this.

Does mailchimp support HTML5 animation? Because when I uploaded HTML5 or simple SVG code by using the following code, the file is not loaded on mailchimp. Hope that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks.

```
<body>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="595.28px" height="841.89px" viewBox="0 0 595.28 841.89" enable-background="new 0 0 595.28 841.89" xml:space="preserve">
  <rect x="23" y="182" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="545" height="291"/>
  </svg>
</body>
```

---

```
<body style="text-align:center;">
    <img height="0" src="graphic.svg" />
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: If the svg / animation is meant to be emailed, I can assure you it won't work in 95%+ of the email clients anyway...

Comment: Ultimately you'll have to ask Mailchimp. Since this question will stay here for eternity, and Mailchimp may change their feature support in the future, this is also a somewhat timely and therefore bad topic for SO.

Comment: @RonaldSwets True, agree with you. But I found a trick from [link](https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-on-svg-support-in-email/) , was thinking may be I'm able to do it.

Comment: @deceze I have emailed Mailchimp, got the reply --> **With animations in particular, we advise against using any <div> elements to apply the style as well as any Javascript, Flash..etc being that most email clients block it....maybe Apple iOS mail I believe may support HTML and CSS3 now.**